# Triangle inequality for distance between parts

Tags: analysis

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, $A,B$ be arbitrary non empty subsets of $X$. Define $d(A,B)=\inf_{x\in{A},y\in{B}}{d(x,y)}$. Does this new function on$[2^X\setminus\emptyset]^2$ satisfy the triangle inequality? (Obviously it is not a distance, since for any proper subset $A\subset X$, $d(X,X\setminus A)=0$, but $X\neq X \setminus A$).
It seems to me that since $\forall a \in A, \forall b \in B, \forall c \in C, d(a,c) \leq d(a,b)+d(b,c)$ by the triangle inequality, $$\inf_{a\in A, b\in B,c\in C}{d(a,b)+d(b,c)}\geq \inf_{a\in A, b \in B}{d(a,c)}$$ and so $d(A,C)\leq d(A,B)+d(B,C)$, but I am not sure I am not missing something.
EDIT: I have a counterexample, so my reasoning must be wrong, but what step is illegitemate here?(Consider the boundary of a square in $\mathbb{R}^2$, let $A$ be the left edge, $B$ the bottom and $C$ the right. Then $d(A,C)>0$ but $d(A,B)+d(B,C)=0$.)

Comment: Often distances like this are defined on compact subsets instead of all subsets.  It makes certain things cleaner.

Comment: Why can you use the same $b$ in both distances?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your proof, you use the same $b\in B$ for both distances on the LHS.  This is not necessarily what happens.

Observe that
$$
d(A,B)+d(B,C)=\inf_{a\in A,b\in B}d(a,b)+\inf_{b'\in B,c\in C}d(b',c)\leq \inf_{a\in A,b\in B,c\in C}d(a,b)+d(b,c).
$$
The inequality shows up because the condition that $b=b'$ is more restrictive.  Therefore, the inequality doesn't work as stated.

In fact, suppose that $A$ and $C$ are disjoint sets whose distance between them is positive and $B=X\setminus (A\cup C)$.  Then $d(A,C)>0$, $d(A,B)=0$, and $d(B,C)=0$.  This describes a counterexample.